# View python code option in qt designer is absent

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I am trying to work with qt designer and I do not see the form>view python code option I see in videos on the software. I tried using the command line uic conversion but I can't figure out how to get it to work, I have anaconda installed and I am not sure how to get the converter to run. I would really like to just be able to use the built in option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the command line, you can type

```
pyuic5 -x yourfilename.ui  -o outputfilename.py
```

**-x**: is used to generate extra code to test and display the class.